# php DOM, get values from xml document, php xml

Tags: php, dom

I'm trying to get some information (`itemID`, `title`, `price` and `mileage`) for multiple listings from eBay website using their api. So far I got [this](http://open.api.ebay.com/shopping?callname=GetMultipleItems&responseencoding=XML&appid=Morcovar-c74b-47c0-954f-463afb69a4b3&siteid=0&version=525&IncludeSelector=ItemSpecifics&ItemID=220617293997,250645537939,230485306218) up

I've saved the document as `.xml` file using PHP cUrl and now I need to get/extract the values(`itemID`, `title`, `price` and `mileage`)  into arrays and store them in database.

Unfortunately I never worked with PHP DOM, and I can't figure out how to extract the values. I tried to follow [the tutorial found on IBM website](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/os-xmldomphp/) but I had no success. Some help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: `simplexml` is the easiest way of extracting XML data in PHP: http://www.php.net/simplexml_load_file

Comment: <pre>
  $doc = new DOMDocument();
   $doc->load( 'api.xml' );
  $items = $doc->getElementsByTagName("GetMultipleItemsResponse");
   foreach( $GetMultipleItemsResponse as $Item )
   {
    $itemID = $Item->getElementsByTagName( "ItemID" );
    $itemID = $Item->item(0)->nodeValue;
   }
   echo $itemID;

</pre>

Comment: that should be an answer instead of a comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a code sample to get the ItemIDs from your XML file:

```
<?php
$doc = new DomDocument();
$doc->load('a.xml');
$response = $doc->getElementsByTagName('GetMultipleItemsResponse')->item(0);
$items = $doc->getElementsByTagName('Item');
foreach ($items as $item)
{
    $itemID = $item->getElementsByTagName('ItemID')->item(0)->nodeValue;
    echo $itemID."\n";
}
?>
```

- `$doc->getElementsByTagName()` returns a DomNodeList. It can be used in a foreach loop, and it has an `item()` method.
- A [DomNodeList](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domnodelist.php) will contain all matching elements. If you know there is only one element, you can retrieve that with `->item(0)`
- The `item()` method returns a [DomElement](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domelement.php), which inherits from [DomNode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domnode.php). DomNode has a nodeValue property, which contains the text within the element.

**Summary**: use [SimpleXML](http://nl.php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php)